# Can I invoke the stream operator overload without a stream object?

Tags: c++

Suppose I want to `throw` with a string containing information about some object, but the object implementation only has an overload for the stream operator (`<<`) rather than a cast to string. I want to do something like this:

```
throw std::runtime_error("Error, encountered invalid value " + x);
```

where `x` is an instance of a type which has (`<<`) overloaded. The above does not work, however, because the `+` is not overloaded to a type compatible with `const char*`. If `x` were a string (or castable to a string) it would work, but instead I have to do this:

```
std::stringstream s;
s << "Error, encountered invalid value " << x;
throw std::runtime_error(s.str());
```

How can I get something as concise as the first example without adding any overloads or custom functions. Does the Standard Library provide some features that will help here?

Comment: overload `operator+(std::string&, X &)`

Comment: Can you not overload the + to add a string to the object?

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond I could, but I'm asking the question to see if it's possible to do it without writing any new functions/overloads at all.

Comment: I dug this out of my history:http://ideone.com/F9eutl  Not advised, but amusing.

Comment: Well in that case more than likely not.  I'm a bit rusty in my C++ overloads and such, but you could make a base object and inherit from that the methods so that you can customize debug output, but if that object code is out of your control then you don't have many options.

Comment: @101010 you mean const references, hopefully

Comment: @MattMcNabb and hopefully overload the reverse case (i.e., `operator+(X const&, std::string const&)`) as well...

Answer (score 4):

You can delegate to a function:

```
template <typename T>
std::string stream(const T& x) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << x;
    return ss.str();
}

throw std::runtime_error("Error..." + stream(x));
```

Which is also what [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) does:

```
throw std::runtime_error("Error..." + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(x));
```

Or you can use a temporary stream, which involves having to do a cast since `operator<<` conventionally returns just a `basic_ostream<char>&`:

```
throw std::runtime_error(
    static_cast<std::ostringstream&&>(std::ostringstream{} << "Error..." << x)
    .str() );
```

Or you can wrap that logic into a separate type which, when streamed, converts the result to a `string`, for amusement's sake:

```
struct ToStrT {
    friend std::string operator<<(std::ostream& os, ToStrT ) {
        return static_cast<std::ostringstream&&>(os).str();
    }
};

constexpr ToStrT ToStr{};

throw std::runtime_error(std::ostringstream{} << "Error..." << x << ToStr);
```

Comment: Quoting my edit summary: "To placate libc++, which returns a `ostringstream&&` in this case, which can't be cast to `ostringstream&`"